# privileges postgresql

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

We have a database server and access is given to the users. Our database resides on this server. It is created using Postgresql. We create tables and perform other operations on different tables within this database through a python script. Right now, the python script, the database tables, and the database are on the same server.

Basically, anybody with access to the server can access the database with its name. The user would have to put the name inside the python script to get access.

How can we give privileges to different users? So, even if users have the access to the database server, we want only selected users can alter the database. How can we achieve that? I found this link - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/user-manag.html. However, my concern is anybody with python script and with the knowledge of the database name will be able to alter the table.

Thanks for your input.

Comment: The document you found explains user management. What is unclear about it or how to set permissions? By definition permissions define what the user can do so why wouldn't setting them correctly help?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit unclear and too broad, but I will try to show you the ropes:

1. You have to have several users in your database:

   - a superuser used for system administration
   - a user that can create objects in the database or at least in a specific schema
   - an application user that has the right to read modify the tables as needed

   There can be more users, for example a user that only has permission to read the tables, but not to modify them.

   If the application creates its own objects, the application user and the object owner are often the same user — convenient, but not ideal from a security point of view.
2. You have to restrict access to the database in `pg_hba.conf`:

   - The superuser should only be allowed in on `local` connections.
   - The object owner should only be allowed to connect from where you deploy your application.
   - The application user should only be allowed to connect from where the application runs.

That way, possession of the Python script that created the database does not mean that people can use it *from everywhere* to destroy your database.

There is much more to database security than this; you should read the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is what I was looking for. Your answer proved to be a good starting point and I was able to solve my problem. Instead of changing pg_hba.conf. I created a schema and a new group with required access rights. I created a new user and put that user in this new group. It seems to be working.